# loglevel-plugin-remote - Send browser logs to server without printing in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, browser, log-level

I am using [loglevel](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel), [loglevel-plugin-prefix](https://github.com/kutuluk/loglevel-plugin-prefix) and [loglevel-plugin-remote](https://github.com/kutuluk/loglevel-plugin-remote) to send frontend logs to the backend in a React App. I want to be able to send the logs to the backend in prod without printing them on the console. Is there a way to do that?

Here's what the code looks like:

```
import * as log from "loglevel";
import prefix from "loglevel-plugin-prefix";
import remote from "loglevel-plugin-remote";


remote.apply(log);
prefix.reg(log);
prefix.apply(log);
log.enableAll();
```

I've tried adding `console.log = () => {};` but that has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

1. Check for production environment.
2. Override methods inside window.console.

All this should be at the top of index.js (or the equivalent).

```
import * as log from "loglevel";
import prefix from "loglevel-plugin-prefix";
import remote from "loglevel-plugin-remote";

...


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    if (!window.console) (window.console as any) = {};
    var methods = [
      "trace",
      "log",
      "debug",
      "warn",
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
      (console as any)[methods[i]] = function () {};
    }
  }

...


remote.apply(log);
prefix.reg(log);
prefix.apply(log);
log.enableAll();


...
```